# How to store and retrieve some block of data from a file in Java?

Tags: android, file

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt files in android. But to get back it's original state I want to store file type metadata to the file.

How can I access it in most efficient way?

Comment: would you be more specific by showing your codes

Answer (score 0):

You can use new Scoped Memory for this:

```
// write to a file
val filename = "myfile"
    val fileContents = "Hello world!"
    context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
            it.write(fileContents.toByteArray())
    }

//read from a file
context.openFileInput(filename).bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
    lines.fold("") { some, text ->
        "$some\n$text"
    }
}
```

FOR MORE INFO CHECK THIS LINK: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific